# mahout Recommender

Tags: java, mahout

The [Apache Mahout Recommender Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/recommender-documentation.html) mentions the following:

```
// Construct the list of pre-computed correlations
Collection <GenericItemSimilarity.ItemItemSimilarity>  correlations = ...;
```

I'm not sure how the actual construction is done in the above line. Can someone provide an example?

```
ItemSimilarity itemSimilarity  =  new GenericItemSimilarity(correlations);
```

Answer (score 3):

This example refers to the case where you have the similarities already computed, by the Hadoop job for example, and stored on the filesystem or database . As the constructor documentation reads:

`A "generic" {@link ItemSimilarity} which takes a static list of precomputed item similarities and bases its responses on that alone. The values may have been precomputed offline by another process, stored in a file, and then read and fed into an instance of this class.`

If you have tens of millions of recommendations or less, you can simply compute similarities on the fly and use the other `GenericItemSimilarity` constructor - `GenericItemSimilarity(ItemSimilarity otherSimilarity, DataModel dataModel)`

For example:

```
DataModel dataModel = new FileDataModel(new File("path://to/file.csv"));
ItemSimilarity itemSimilarity = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(dataModel);
ItemSimilarity itemSimilarity = new GenericItemSimilarity(itemSimilarity, dataModel);
```

Comment: "If you have tens of millions of recommendations or less, you can simply compute similarities on the fly" -> using the 10M movielens data, itembased recommendations take about 22 seconds to load.. user-based only took 200ms. How can you load tens of millions on the fly with item-based?

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic here, it's just suggesting you create a bunch of those ItemItemSimilarity objects, one for each item-item similarity that you know about.

```
Collection<GenericItemSimilarity.ItemItemSimilarity> correlations = 
  new ArrayList<GenericItemSimilarity.ItemItemSimilarity>();
correlations.add(new GenericItemSimilarity.ItemItemSimilarity(1, 2, 0.5));
...
```

You can make it this way or any other way you want.

Comment: I have created a correlation Collection as you have mentioned here and created then following similarity instance: new CachingItemSimilarity(new GenericItemSimilarity(correlations),dataModel.getNumItems()); .. Using the 1M MovieLens data my item-based recommender is only 40-50% faster than before (like 589.5ms instead 1222.9ms). But User-based instead is really fast, it´s like 24.2ms? How can this happen? And is my precomputation of item similarities ok? I hope you have a bit time for me too :)